# Symbol for ideal voltage source vs symbol for real voltage source

Tags: symbol, ideal

Wikipedia's article on [Voltage source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_source#Ideal_voltage_sources) shows the figure below. It says in the figure that the following symbols is an *ideal* voltage source.

[image]

However, elsewhere in the same article they have a circuit using the same symbol, and they call it a *real* voltage source.

[image]

I need to make some illustrations for some teaching material, and I need to make the distinction between ideal and real voltage sources. How do I do that? Do I need to add a small label to each circuit diagram explicitly stating whether it is ideal or real? Or can I communicate this clearly by using symbols?

If possible I would like answers to refer to standards or other canonical sources if there are any.

Comment: That's the symbol for a voltage source, ideal or real. Same for current source.

Comment: i think, if memory serves me well,  "real voltage source" has a resistor associated with it... i.e. your symbol with a resistor (your 2nd symbol).... that's all i got :)

Comment: if you need to make a distinction you could use the battery symbol wherever you need a real voltage source.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of little niggles in wikipedia, such might be expected from a large collaborative amateur effort, this is one of them.

Ideally, a real voltage source ought to be depicted like this, if the only non-ideality that's being modelled is the internal impedance. It's the principal non-ideality. We tend to ignore noise, drift, strange current limits, and changes in effective Rinternal in favour of this simple model.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0Y70J.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Either that, or the diagram you've picked out ought just to be labelled a plain voltage source. It is now ;-). It's difficult to know what's for the best, without a major overhaul of the article. For instance, what on earth is the PO Box paragraph doing in there? It's unnecessary and insufficient!